# How to use UnCSS with XAMPP

Tags: php, css, node.js, xampp

Although there's some basic information out there on how to install and use UnCSS through Node.js, I'd like to run it on a site I have running on my localhost (via XAMPP).

I'm very new to Node.js, I have it installed and ran through a few of the tutorials, but that's it so my background knowledge is beginner at best.  I ran "npm install -g uncss" and installed it locally.  But when I run it on a localhost site via a command prompt via:

```
uncss http://localhost/site/ > stylesheet.css
```

...it always generates a blank "stylesheet.css" file.  I'm sure I made a mistake at some point during install or usage.

Can you help guide me through the correct steps to make UnCSS work with a local site running under XAMPP?

Comment: does `http://localhost/site` actually have any content that uses CSS? If not, then yes, stylesheet.css will be empty, because none of your in-that-page-linked-stylesheet code ends up being used.

Comment: Yup, on that particular localhost/site there are several stylesheets, including jqueryui.css which I know that only a small amount of the styles are being used. UnCSS seems to be missing this and the other stylesheets.

Comment: did you remember to tell uncss of those hard dependencies? (I see some mention of that on http://npmjs.org/package/uncss)

Comment: Hmm...since I was running UnCSS from the command line, I didn't think it used any outside options (i.e. hard dependencies).  Do I need an "uncss.js" file in the root of the localhost site to declare these options?

Comment: Hm, not sure. Might be worth asking as an issue on their tracker in addition to asking on SO